# Why doesn't github actions CI compile with same jdk?

Tags: java, github-actions

I have Scala code that successfully builds locally on JDK 13.0.1.

```scala
s.getValue().stripTrailing()  // s.getValue() returns String
```

When this code is built by github actions I get this error:

```
Error:  -- [E008] Not Found Error: /github/workspace/core/src/main/scala/co.blocke.scalajack/yaml/YamlParser.scala:45:96 
Error:  45 |          case "|" | ">"                           => s.getValue().stripTrailing()
Error:     |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error:     |                           value stripTrailing is not a member of String
```

My action file is:

```yaml
name: Package Build
# This workflow is triggered on pushes to the repository.
on: 
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - "feature/*"  # don't run build/test against a feature branch -- no SLA there
      - "master"

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 13
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '13.0.1'
      - name: Test
        id: sbt
        uses: lokkju/github-action-sbt@master
        with:
          commands: test
```

stripTrailing() is a method on String in both Oracle and OpenJDK 13.x libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action `github-action-sbt` uses a Docker container internally ([source](https://github.com/lokkju/github-action-sbt/blob/f87bca5b8260ae4846c4f311165e3502e365e8b0/action.yml)). Your step `Set up JDK 13` only works for things that run directly on the runner, but it doesn't affect containers.

**Solution**

Specify a tag in the format `{JAVA_VERSION}-{SBT_VERSION}-{SCALA_VERSION}`. See below for available versions.

```
      - name: Test
        id: sbt
        uses: lokkju/github-action-sbt@14-1.3.0-2.10.7
        with:
          commands: test
```

> The tag controls the version of Java, SBT, and Scala that the image is initialized with. SBT and Scala will auto-download other versions as specified in your project settings, but if they don't match the initialized versions, it can take significant extra build time.
>
> The tag format is `{JAVA_VERSION}-{SBT_VERSION}-{SCALA_VERSION}` Currently supported tags are:
>
> ```
> JAVA_VERSIONS=("8" "11" "14")
> SBT_VERSIONS=("0.13.17" "1.1.6" "1.2.8" "1.3.0")
> SCALA_VERSIONS=("2.13.0" "2.12.10" "2.11.12" "2.10.7")
> ```

[source at time of creation of this post](https://github.com/lokkju/github-action-sbt/tree/f87bca5b8260ae4846c4f311165e3502e365e8b0#action-tags)

[source @master](https://github.com/lokkju/github-action-sbt/#action-tags)